# Single forEach loop for loading values in both Selection box(Drop Down Box) and Input text/hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstl

I have one List- `sampleList`, in which I have both Sample Name and corresponding country name. I need to Display Sample Name in a drop down box and corresponding country name in a hidden field. Following are the code which I used.

```
     <select id="sampleId">
            <c:forEach var="options" items="${sampleList}" varStatus="i">
                   <option value="${options.sampleName}" >${options.countryname}</option>
            </c:forEach>
     </select>
     <c:forEach var="options" items="${sampleList}" varStatus="i">
            <input type="hidden" value="${options.countryname}" id="${options.countryname}_country"/>
     </c:forEach>
```

My doubt is that, is it possible to use single `forEach` loop for loading values in both Selection box (Drop Down Box) and Input hidden field.

Comment: Unless each hidden input can sit right below each `option` element in the DOM, I would assume no.

Comment: We cannot use Input field with each option . it won't work

Comment: @MaheshNarayanan Can you use data attribute?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to use single forEach loop for loading values in both Selection box (Drop Down Box) and Input hidden field.

It's possible if you  put [HTML5 data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) instead of Input hidden field inside `forEach` loop.

```
<select id="sampleId">
    <c:forEach var="options" items="${sampleList}" varStatus="i">
           <option value="${options.sampleName}"
                   data-country="${options.countryname}"
                   id="${options.countryname}_country">${options.countryname}
           </option>
    </c:forEach>
 </select>
```